# Manual set parameters for POST-request over curl

Tags: bash, curl

I have simple script. Script can be run with specific arguments.
For example:

```
./my-script.sh --last-name=Smith --first-name=John
```

There is called `curl` and sended POST-request in script:

```
curl --data-urlencode last_name=$lastName --data-urlencode first_name=$firstName https://example.com
```

Where `firstName` and `lastName` are variables, that parsed from arguments.

Issue, that firstName or lastName (but not both) can be missed. If argument is missed, appropriate parameter do not sended to server.

But I do not know, how I can implement this logic in scripts.

Ofcouse, I can add `if` to check argument on null, but I can have much arguments in command line and in this case I will have tons of `if`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this: suppose

```
arg1=myname
arg2=
```

Then in order to include only non-empty parameters, code:

```
command="curl "
if [ "$arg1" != "" ]; then
        command="$command --data-urlencode arg1=$arg1"
fi
if [ "$arg2" != "" ]; then
        command="$command --data-urlencode arg2=$arg2"
fi

echo $command
```

You have one `if` statement for each variable.

Comment: Thanks. `curl ...  $argumets` works for me.

Comment: I still have only one not understanding moment. I trying send request with file. So, I'm use `-F first_name=... -F last_name=... -F photo=@./file.jpg`. but argument and filename can contains spaces. I can fix it from command line:  `-F "first_name=..." -F "last_name=..." -F "photo=@..."`. But I get empty arguments on server, if use variable (command): `command+="-F \"first_name=...\""` (request contain parameter, but it's empty).